# Identity Server 3 ADFS and Asp.Net Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs, identityserver3, asp.net-identity-2

Looking for a bit of advice regarding best practice regarding multiple user stores.

Currently I have Identity Server 3 set up using a factory method to connect to an Asp.Net Identity V2 user store.

I have two MVC Relying Party applications, both using OWIN to pass un-authenticated requests to the Identity Server.

Within Identity Server, both RP client applications are set up using Hybrid flow.

Now my question:
I want to have the Identity Server use mutiple user stores (in my case, we have users authenticating via our Identity V2 Store and also via ADFS)

I'm not sure how to detect or tell the which kind of user is connecting to the RP client application, and I'm not sure how to pass this information to Identity Server so that it can make a decision on which user store to use.

Any help greatly appreciated.